# How do I stub a named_scope so .find can still be called on the resultset?

Tags: rspec, named-scope, stub, rspec-rails, method-chaining

I'm mantaining a Rails app.

Controller old code:

```
@articles = Articles.unpublished.find(complicated_conditions)
```

I'm changing it to something like this:

```
if logged_user.has_a_specific_permission
  @articles = Articles.unpublished.find(complicated_conditions)
else
  @articles = Articles.unpublished.find(another_hash_of_complicated_conditions)
end
```

I want to write a spec for my change but I don't think testing the conditions is the best way to test the feature (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

So in my spec I wanted to have something like:

```
login_as(user_with_specific_permission)
permitted = stub('permitted article')
prohibited = stub('prohibited article')
Articles.stub!(:unpublished).and_return([permitted, prohibited])
get :index
assigns[:articles].should eql([permitted])
```

, to test if the conditions are filtering the results as expected, but this doesn't work because I can't call .find with conditions in an Array.

So what's the way to test this feature?

**tl;dr:** I want to stub the first part of a method chain but I can't return an Array, and I don't know what I should return.